# Hover element, show hover effect on parent elements siblings child

Tags: html, css, hover, css-selectors, parent-child

Let's see now, not sure if I have the logic down 100%.

This is what I'm working with (bootply demo [**here**](http://bootply.com/95935))

```
<ul>
    <li class="row">
        <span class="category col-sm-2 highlight">Architecture</span> 
        <span class="title col-sm-4"><a href="#">Hello world!</a></span>
        <span class="publication col-sm-2 hidden-xs">Magazine</span>
        <span class="year col-sm-2 hidden-xs">2007</span>  
    </li>
    <li class="row">
        <span class="category col-sm-2 invisible">Architecture</span> 
        <span class="title col-sm-4"><a href="#">Keep them coming</a></span>
        <span class="publication col-sm-2 hidden-xs">Magazine</span>
        <span class="year col-sm-2 hidden-xs">2007</span>  
    </li>
    <li class="row">
        <span class="category col-sm-2 invisible">Architecture</span> 
        <span class="title col-sm-4"><a href="#">The other posts</a></span>
        <span class="publication col-sm-2 hidden-xs">Magazine</span>
        <span class="year col-sm-2 hidden-xs">2007</span>  
    </li>
    <li class="row">
        <span class="category col-sm-2">Cities</span> 
        <span class="title col-sm-4"><a href="#">Tezt</a></span>
        <span class="publication col-sm-2 hidden-xs">Magazine</span>
        <span class="year col-sm-2 hidden-xs">2007</span>  
    </li>
</ul>
```

The idea is that, when hovering the a element in `span.title`, the color of the text in publication and year is changed. I'm also looking for a way to change the color of the first `span.category` of the same kind (i.e. hovering "The other post" should change the color of `span.category` in the first `.row`). Is this achievable with pure CSS?

Comment: I doubt. Scripting would be required along with css.

Comment: Not just with CSS, I'm afraid

Comment: Why not make the hover on li, and make css like: li:hover .title{...}, li:hover .category{...}

Comment: You're here looking to hover `Architecture` when any of the span with that category is hovered right?

Comment: @user2549787 Exactly!

Comment: @Andrew Because I wish that the hover area would be restricted to the a element in span.title only..

Comment: @INT I don't think this is possible with pure css as you can't select a previous sibling :S

Comment: @nkmol solved with pure css :)

Comment: @Mr. Alien Meh i'm missing something. I really would love to vote your question up, but is see no relation to the question the OP orignally posted. The OP is fine with it. But still he did not explain what you just did? Check my comment on your answer what i mean.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got your point what you are trying to do here, in this case, you can use the selector below.. so that when the `li` is hovered, it will also apply the color to the first `span`

```
.row:hover span:nth-of-type(1) {
   color: red;
}
```

I just inspected the DOM in your fiddle and I would like to alter some things in that..

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/n5CcV/) (`hover` an of the *hello* and see the very first `span` color will be changed)

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/n5CcV/1/) (DOM Altered) - This is just a general idea, I've provided you the selector but this will need the DOM alteration anyways..

---

Altered [**Demo**](http://bootply.com/95941) in your Code

---

Again as per your comment, now you can highlight all `span` along with their titles

```
ul li div.row:hover > span {
   color: red;
}
```

[**Final Demo**](http://bootply.com/95942)

Comment: +1 from me, you got back your merit to positive which you deserve ;) - @Mr.Alien

Comment: Make that "perfect" - @BindiyaPatoliya

Comment: Yea that was me :) He did say when hovering the `.title` element, now the first element will always be changed when you hover `.row` not ONLY when you hover `.title`. IMO, this isn't possible in CSS as you can't select a previous sibling.

Comment: I would wish the anonymous downvoter should mention the reason to justify the negative.

Comment: what is your problem? - @user2549787

Comment: [Here's the post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20139856/bootstrap-3-affix-width-of-the-div-the-getting-changed-of-scroll). Please help me. Stuck with `Bootstrap 3 Aiifx`

Comment: @Mr.Alien You still don't use the DOM order as OP showed. He basically want whenever he hover the `.title` element select the next 2 siblings, but ALSO the sibling before that element. Which isn't possible in css. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n5CcV/3/)

Comment: This is superb @Mr.Alien, you solved what I didn't think was possible! :) How about selecting the spans other spans in the same row? (http://i.imgur.com/6xrtLaQ.png)

Comment: @user2549787 provided another demo in my answer, check it out, I've altered your code

Comment: @Mr.Alien- I'm sorry. Couldn't find any answer and no changes in the demo I've given.

Comment: @Nathan - Sorry. It's for Mr.Alien. And I've given the link for a post. Can you please help me out?

Comment: @user2549787 you can check the final demo, and am off to lunch, see you guys in a while, I hope the final demo suffices your needs

Comment: @user2549787 - Yes, got it, no worries :)

Comment: @Mr.Alien - You're seriously weird. I didn't make that post. It was INT who did it and I was asking help for another [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20139856/bootstrap-3-affix-width-of-the-div-the-getting-changed-of-scroll) :).

Comment: This is really great @Mr.Alien thanks so much! And wow, I didn't expect such interest :)

Comment: I noticed now that it's the li element that triggers everything. Would it be possible to change so that `span.title a` triggers everything or is that impossible?

Comment: @user2549787 I am not even aware who is the original user to ask this question lol.. -INT changing the DOM is the real thing here, everything is triggered using `li div` so as far as your cursor stays in the parent element, the title will be colored, and my second selector helps you color all the `span` on `hover` of their parent `div` and you welcome :) also last but not the least, if you hover over your title, the second `span` wont be colored as it's `a` so use this to target the `span` as well http://bootply.com/95948, you can also use `a {color: inherit;}` instead :)

Comment: @INT and if you are thinking that hovering the title will color all the related rows than the answer is no you cannot.. you can highlight one row at a time

Comment: @Mr.Alien I see, would there perhaps be any use in looking into some sort of js solution to keep the related spans black while unless `span.title` specifically is hovered?

Comment: @INT if it is really important to you than yes, JS is a way to go, if this functionality isn't crucial than you can leave JS